# TV as display that rotates multiple monitors

Tags: tv

I have multiple monitor setup and I wish to show the screens on a TV one at a time for "X" second intervals before showing the next.  Preferable that I can specify which screens (ie may only be 2 of the 4 screens)

Hoping someone might have suggestions on how I could do this.

Thanks, Shane

Comment: What is a "5 second display"? And what do you mean by rotating the display to a TV? Do you mean duplicating some screens and not others? Or showing the screens on a TV one at a time for 5 second intervals? Could you use the EDIT button and add some details and clarify your points so we can better understand your question?